# Javascript HTML5 Capture keyCode and write to Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, keycode

I'm writing an application in which I need to simulate a textarea.  The only way I know how to approach it is to capture the keyCode on a key event.  How would one go about taking that keyCode and, supporting utf-8, apply that to the canvas?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea since there is an awful lot over and above text input that a textarea gives you for free (caret, selection, cut, paste, drag and drop, arrow key handling, etc.), but here's two things you need to do :

1. Give your `<canvas>` a `tabindex` attribute so that it may receive focus and hence raise key events;
2. Add a `keypress` (not `keydown`) handler to the `<canvas>` element to capture text input.

Code:

```
<canvas id="textarea" tabindex="1" width="300" height="200"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var el = document.getElementById("textarea");
   el.onkeypress = function(evt) {
       var charCode = evt.which;
       var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
       alert(charStr);
   };
</script>
```

Comment: I think you may be right, it seems like an awful lot of work to replicate a textarea and I actually don't see any advantages of keeping a textarea out (it's not really an application, but more of an edutainment game where everything is happening in a canvas element but need to recieve text input).  I *think* putting a transparent textarea over my canvas is the best possible solution.

Comment: While keypress captures character codes, it doesn't capture backspaces. Why use keypress instead of keydown?

Comment: @DavidR.: I'd use `keydown` for backspace and delete support. For collecting text input, though, `keypress` is the only key event that gives you data about the characters typed so is the only choice. See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: @Tim-Down, fantastic resource! Just to summarize what I understand from research in that article and elsewhere, the difference is scan code (keydown) v. character code (keypress). Keydown will recognize what keys are being pressed, but doesn't inform about combinations of keys (e.g. shift/caps-lock). This worked fine for my case because case wasn't an issue, but using keydown won't define a state of capitalization. Also, as the article illustrates, keydown isn't culturally agnostic and will limit localization/language issues. Highly recommend that article though, very insightful.

Comment: @DavidR.: Yes, that tallies with my understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery:

```
<div id="myTextArea></div>

$('#myTextArea').keypress(function (event) {

    $('#myTextArea').append(String.fromCharCode(event.which));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Bespin](https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/)? It is more than just a textarea replacement, but it basically does what you want. You could certainly look into the code and documentation, or if it fits your needs, just use it.

Comment: I'll rephrase - it accomplishes the specific requirement they inquired about: "Javascript HTML5 Capture keyCode and write to Canvas" As a purely canvas based text editor, they capture keys typed in and display it using canvas - amongst other things.